# Spark Glue job failing with no space left on the device

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to run the spark glue job with 2.x configuration where using 50 workers and 16 cores but still job is failing with no space left on the device. it is always pointing to one executor at the end then it throws space issue.

Also I used --writes_shuffles_to_s3 as well as --writes_spills_to_s3 both value as true
As well as given the s3 location for glue shuffle but still ut is behaving same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: giving code is tough as it is into some different environment...however the issue is resolved by removing the views and directly querying the tables inside those views.

Now I am wondering why glue is taking so much time while running the aws glue job with the view and it is continuously running.